# Default site when using apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am hosting two domains using the virtual host directive

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xy
    ServerName xyz
    ServerAlias www.xyz

    DocumentRoot  /var/www/sites/xyz

    <Directory /var/www/sites/xyz>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xy
    ServerName xyz2
    ServerAlias www.xyz2

    DocumentRoot  /var/www/sites/xyz2

    <Directory /var/www/sites/xyz2>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

When I access the site using the bare IP address I am directed to the first virtual host xyz. I would like to be directed to the default webiste /var/www/html

how can I achieve that? If I create a virtual host with the server IP address ... what would the server name be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the IP as the server name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 12.345.67.89
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
         ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or you could leave it blank to act as a default as per Stasik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and search for "Main host goes away". Just add a new first virtual host without name and alias, it will match the requests that are not mached by any following vitrtual hosts.